# How can you show that $E(Y\mid E(Y\mid X)) = E(Y\mid X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to show that  $E(Y\mid E(Y\mid X)) = E(Y\mid X)$. However, I cannot see how to do this without integrals.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{E}$ *defined* as an integral, how can you do this without integration?

Comment: Let $Z=E[Y|X]$. Then $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, i.e, $\sigma(Z) \subset \sigma(X)$, and hence by the tower property, one has $E[Y|Z] = E\big[E[Y|X]\big|Z\big] = E[Z|Z]=Z$. Of course, in order to actually prove the tower property, one must write out everything based on definitions and hence use integrals.